# Legitimacy of the usage of "homeworks"

Tags: word-usage

Teachers and students sometimes refer to *homework assignments* as "homeworks". Is that an acceptable usage?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many ordinarily mass nouns can be and frequently are used as count nouns shortened from compounds. _Homeworks_ comes from _homework assignments_, and that's what it hasta mean. It is fully acceptable, or it wouldn't be used. If you wish to correct the usage of the teachers and students who do this, feel free to do so. No doubt they will appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @John Lawler Isn't 'incitement to cause riot' on the statute books over there?

Comment: John Lawler, it would be helpful if you mention where in the world it is acceptable. I have not heard it used in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

[Homework](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/homeworks), not 'homeworks':

> - or homework assignment, refers to tasks assigned to students by their teachers to be completed outside of class. Common homework assignments may include a quantity or period of reading to be performed, writing or typing to be completed, problems to be solved, a school project to be built (such as a diorama or display), or other skills to be practiced.

Here are three usage  examples:

- I have three homework assignments.
- I have three assignments.
- I have two hours of homework to do tonight.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=homework%2Chomeworks&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chomework%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chomeworks%3B%2Cc0) homework vs  homeworks

Comment: _Coffee_, not 'coffees'. Customers continue to ask for "two coffees", and it's important to tell them that they **should** be asking for _two cups of coffee_, because if they persist in this, someone will think they're not well educated.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, just showing evidence. Language is very much alive, we all know.

Comment: So is that one countification or two?

Comment: Josh61, your answer would be improved if you mention where in the world the word *assignment*, is used in this context. I have not heard it used in the UK.

Comment: @Tristan - Homework assignments is widely used in AmE, but it appears to be fairly common also in BrE also. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=homework+assignments&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chomework%20assignments%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Josh61, I never heard it used at all in the multiple schools that I went to, in the UK. That was also the case with people that I knew at other schools. In my day, *homework* was just called *homework*. It was as simple as that.